# ARCore get/show bounding box over subset of PointCloud points?

Tags: android, collision-detection, point-clouds, bounding-box, arcore

Trying to use ARCore for detecting objects.

Anyone know of an example to calculate an oriented collision bounding box and display it as an ARSceneView Node from a subset of PointCloud points in a frame?

I've tried using the Axis Aligned Bounding Box method (calculate min/max of all axes), but that doesn't give me orientation and is also too big if the object is rotated.
It also seems to only work on a single frame.  If I accumulate high confidence points across frames, the 3D points seem to move enough that the bounding box calculated is the wrong size.
Are PointCloud points non-comparable between frames?

ArCore doesn't include the PCL library unfortunately.